# How do I estimate a smooth cdf from a set of observations?

Tags: density-function, curve-fitting, cumulative-distribution-function, nonparametric

I have a set of observation, let's call it $X$ and would like to fit a cdf to it. $X$ has a distribution which is roughly approximable with the normal distribution. This CDF should correspond to a continuous distribution function.

So far I've used a parametric approach by estimating mean and standard deviation and using a normal cdf but I would like to know what other options are available and how to use them.

How does the set of available option change if I require the cdf to be a smooth curve?

Comment: Search our site for *kernel density estimation* (or try the `kernel-density-estimate` [tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density-estimate), on which there are hundreds of posts. For example, there's one with pictures [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68999/how-to-smear-a-histogram/). There are other forms of nonparametric density estimation, but this is the most common. There's also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). It's a standard function in many stats packages.  ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... this gives a smooth *pdf*, as a finite mixture of the density of the kernel. One way to get a smooth cdf, is to take the cdf corresponding to that kernel and take the same mixture over it. (... now I read the answer more closely, I see that's what it's getting at, but I'll leave my comment as it offers more detail, including an easy way to get a bandwidth, even if it's not optimal for the cdf).

Comment: A rougher but simpler method to program would simply cumulate the density (scaled by the gap in x-values), which you could do in R like so: `y=rgamma(100,10,1);plot(ecdf(y));d=density(y);` 
`lines(d$x,cumsum(d$y)*(d$x[2]-d$x[1]),type="l",col=2,lwd=2)`

Comment: To get the first thing, replace that "lines" command above with something like (remove semicolons if you don't do it all on one line): `h=d(y)$bw;`
`r=diff(range(y));`
`xx=seq(min(y)-r/10,max(y)+r/7,.1);`
`cdf=rowSums(outer(xx,y,function(x,y) pnorm(x,y,h)))/length(y);`
`lines(xx,cdf,col=4,lwd=2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be the CDF of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  For various positive real values of $h$ you could compute:
$$
G_h(x) = \frac{h}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{n} F\left(h \cdot (x_i-x)\right).
$$

This is the resulting CDF from doing Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) with a Gaussian Kernel.  Essentially, that is, replacing each of your data points with a small Normal Distribution.  Unfortunately, I don't have time to write the R code.

Comment: ok that's fine, I upvoted anyway since it is useful, thanks.

Comment: A more usual notation would use a capital letter for cdf and reserve a lower case for pdf. Similarity to the usual exposition for a kernel density estimate (combined with explicit mention of it) tricked me for a minute, until I read more closely. I imagine I wouldn't be the only one.

Comment: @Glen_b Edited, thanks.  My phone alerted me that someone said it was the PDF, and when I got here all I saw was this nice message.  Always feel free to edit my posts (if you could possibly remember this comment)

Comment: If it suits you, feel free to use the R code in the comment above.

Comment: @jlimahaverford: I think there is a slight mistake in that the factor $h$ should not appear in front, contrary to the density estimate (as it integrates out by a change of variable).